# SQL -PIVOT Table using dynamic value

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am struggling with a scenario which I have to use PIVOT table. This

Below is the source Data. The first source Table contains Name and Employee No. and second table which is the child of first, contains Hiredate and TermDate with EmployeeId as ForeignKey

2 Tables.

**Employees Table**

```
ID     Name  EmployeeNo
----   ----  ----------
1      James   ABC
2      Allen   DEF
```

**Employee Details Table**

```
EmployeeId    HireDate      TerminationDate
----------    ---------     ---------------
     1        10/01/2001
     2        12/31/2017     01/01/2019
```

**Expected Result**

```
JAMES     JAMES HIRE DATE    JAMES TERM DATE     ALLEN    ALLEN HIRE DATE    ALLEN TERM DATE
------    ---------------    ---------------     -----    ---------------    ---------------
ABC        10/01/2001                             DEF      12/31/2017         01/01/2019
```

I was able to bring in the below order

```
   JAMES    ALLEN    JAMES HIRE DATE    ALLEN HIRE DATE   JAMES TERM DATE   ALLEN TERM DATE
   ------   -------   ---------------    ---------------   ---------------   --------------- 
     ABC     DEF       10/01/2001          12/31/2017                          01/01/2019
```

But my client insists on getting it done

Below is the code i have so far

```
CREATE TABLE #Employees (
    ID BIGINT
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(100)
    ,[EmployeeNo] VARCHAR(100)
    );

CREATE TABLE #EmployeeHireDetails (
    EmployeeId BIGINT
    ,HireDate DATETIME
    ,TermDate DATETIME
    );

INSERT INTO #Employees (ID,[Name],EmployeeNo) VALUES (1,'James','ABC')
INSERT INTO #Employees (ID,[Name],EmployeeNo) VALUES (2,'Allen','DEF')

INSERT INTO #EmployeeHireDetails (EmployeeId,HireDate,TermDate) VALUES (1,DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE()),NULL)
INSERT INTO #EmployeeHireDetails (EmployeeId,HireDate,TermDate) VALUES (2,DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()),DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE()))

DECLARE @EmpName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,@EmpHireDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,@EmpTermDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SELECT UPPER(E.Name) AS EmployeeName
    ,UPPER(E.Name) + ' ' + 'HIRE DATE' AS EmployeeHireDate
    ,UPPER(E.Name) + ' ' + 'TERM DATE' AS EmployeeTermDate
    ,EmployeeNo
    ,EH.EmployeeId
    ,EH.HireDate
    ,EH.TermDate
INTO #Emps
FROM #Employees E WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #EmployeeHireDetails EH WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON E.ID = EH.EmployeeId

SET @EmpName = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(EmployeeName)
            FROM #Emps
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @EmpNameQry NVARCHAR(MAX)  

SET @EmpNameQry = 'SELECT *                 
   FROM (            
   SELECT E.EmployeeNo           
     ,UPPER(E.EmployeeName) EmployeeName            
     --,E.EmployeeId AS EmpName_EmployeeId          
    FROM #Emps E            
    INNER JOIN #Employees EId            
     ON E.EmployeeId = EId.ID               
    ) p            
   Pivot(Max(EmployeeNo) FOR EmployeeName IN (' + @EmpName + ')) AS Pivot_table'

EXEC sp_executesql @EmpNameQry

DECLARE @EmpHireDateQry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @EmpHireDate = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(EmployeeHireDate)
            FROM #Emps
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @EmpHireDateQry = 'SELECT *                 
   FROM (            
  SELECT E.HireDate           
    ,EmployeeHireDate               
    FROM #Emps E            
    INNER JOIN #Employees EId            
     ON E.EmployeeId = EId.ID                
    ) p            
   Pivot(Max(HireDate) FOR EmployeeHireDate IN (' + @EmpHireDate + ')) AS Pivot_table2'

EXEC sp_executesql @EmpHireDateQry


DECLARE @EmpTermDateQry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @EmpTermDate = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(EmployeeTermDate)
            FROM #Emps
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SET @EmpHireDateQry = 'SELECT *                 
   FROM (            
  SELECT E.TermDate           
    ,EmployeeTermDate               
    FROM #Emps E            
    INNER JOIN #Employees EId            
     ON E.EmployeeId = EId.ID                
    ) p            
   Pivot(Max(TermDate) FOR EmployeeTermDate IN (' + @EmpTermDate + ')) AS Pivot_table3'

EXEC sp_executesql @EmpHireDateQry

DROP TABLE #EmployeeHireDetails
DROP TABLE #Employees
DROP TABLE #Emps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE and conditional aggregation. The column names are hard coded. You may have to use a dynamic query to generate column names when you cannot hard code the column names.

```
with jt as
(
select t1.Name, t1.EmployeeNo, t2.HireDate, t2.TerminationDate
from employee t1
inner join employeeDetails t2 on t2.EmployeeID = t1.ID
)
select
    max(case when Name = 'James' then EmployeeNo end) as JAMES,
    max(case when Name = 'James' then HireDate end) as 'JAMES HIRE DATE',
    max(case when Name = 'James' then TerminationDate end) as 'JAMES TERMINATION DATE',
    max(case when Name = 'Allen' then EmployeeNo end) as ALLEN,
    max(case when Name = 'Allen' then HireDate end) as 'ALLEN HIRE DATE',
    max(case when Name = 'Allen' then TerminationDate end) as 'ALLEN TERMINATION DATE'
from jt
```